# How I can send pictures and Commands "through" a socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Hi i want to send pictures from my Computer to a rasberry or other Pc. They should work with this pictures later.
But their should be a method to say the rasberry or Pc to delete a special picture so how I can do this?

Comment: Do you now a script wich allow me to send .txt data or pictures or a side were I can learn about sockets??

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is to define your protocol. You can use a known protocol like WebDAV or HTTP, or define your own protocol. You can start with a simple protocol like (The brackets down't belong to the protocol. They are just showing the communication direction):

```
> DELETE pictures/my_picture.png
< OK
> SAVE pictures/anoter.jpg
> [length]
> [image-data]
< OK
> DELETE pictures/my_picture.png
< ERROR not found
```

You can implement the server by using sockets directly, or using `xinetd` which is quite simple.

Comment: As I mentioned before you can use `xinetd` which provides a socket server for you. Your server reads the commands from `stdin` and writes results to `stdout`. It's very straightforward. If you want to implement a socket server by yourself you should take a look into the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html It's a good starting point.